# Why I am getting a strange DNS server in my dhcp client android phone?

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

Sorry for bad english.
I have a DHCP server router with IP 192.168.0.254
Everything goes well, but my phone and my tablet gets a very strange DNS 1 server: `80980492081`

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

This is very strange and is getting me mad. I don't know where that strange DNS 1 server comes from. My DHCP server settings are right.

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S5

Does anybody know what is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: DHCP? Aren't you showing the _manual_ settings screen?

Comment: Yes. That's because to show what dhcp parameters got the phone. 1st I set as dhcp. 2nd connect, 3rd, set as static to view what parameters got.

Comment: But this window _doesn't_ show DHCP received parameters. Even if you do what you described, it only shows previously entered manual parameters.

Comment: I do this because IP tools doesn't show this DNS 1 server. It shows the supposed right settings. Nonetheless when I try to ping a host defined in my DNS server I get error, because my phone isn't using my DNS server :(

Comment: I have confirmed:
Set right DNS server as static parameter. Changed to DHCP. Received that strange unknown DNS server. Switch back to static, and the strange DNS server setting shows. Not the last good one.

Comment: From GUI set to DHCP. Switch WiFi OFF and ON. Execute this command in `adb shell`: `dumpsys connectivity | grep CONNECTED | grep -o 'Routes: .* DnsAddresses: [^ ]*'`. This shows you the DNS and default gateway addresses received from DHCP server.

Comment: @IrfanLatif
 CONNECTED | grep -o 'Routes: .* DnsAddresses: [^ ]*'                         <
Routes: [fe80::/64 -> :: wlan0,192.168.0.0/24 -> 0.0.0.0 wlan0,0.0.0.0/0 -> 192.168.0.254 wlan0,] DnsAddresses: [fe80::9e80:dfff:fe49:2081%wlan0,192.1
68.0.254,]
Routes: [] DnsAddresses: []
shell@klte:/ $
What does it mean? Am I getting an IPv6 address as DNS server?

Comment: Yes, that's an IPv6 address. Your ISP must be providing IPv6 services. You might also have an IPv6 address assigned to router from ISP. If not, disable IPv6 on router (and possibly on Android if rooted).

Comment: Problem confirmed and solved. I have deactivated al IPv6 related things in all of my hosts, and that strange address has gone away. Everything comes back to normality and working Ok again. Thank you very much Irfan Latif

Answer (score 0):

An IPv4 address is a 32bit number. The common way to print an IPv4 address is to split it into 4 8bit blocks and separate them with a dot.

However an IPv4 address is also valid in it's decimal/integer representation. This decimal representation is used for your DNS IP address: `80980492081`.

Converting the number in the common IPv4 address format ends up with the IP address: `218.208.63.49`.

https://www.vultr.com/resources/ipv4-converter/?ip_address=80980492081

Comment: Only if you use converters which do not check the input at all. 80980492081 or hex 0x12DAD03F31 is at least a 37-bit number and does not make sense as an IP address – Vultr's converter quietly ignores the extra parts. (Besides, why would the software arbitrarily show an IP address in full-decimal format?)

Comment: @grawity Good catch. Would be interesting what Linux/Android does in such a case. If it just ignores the bits higher than 32 (uses the number modulo 2^32)?

Comment: Maybe, but in that case the number cannot _possibly_ be coming from DHCP (as the packet format only has a 32-bit field) – it can only come from manual input or from some unusual software bug.